# How do search engines treat content shown by :target?

Tags: css, seo, search-engine, web-crawler, information-hiding

For pages with a lot of content I've recently become fond of using css :target to show only the desired content. The code may look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {font-family:sans-serif;}
    #some-content>*,
    #some-content>*:target ~ h2:last-of-type,
    #some-content>*:target ~ h2:last-of-type+* { display: none; }

    #some-content>h2:target,
    #some-content>h2:target+*,
    #some-content>h2:last-of-type,
    #some-content>h2:last-of-type+* { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#test-1">First link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test-2">Second link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test-3">Third link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test-4">Fourth link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test-5">Fifth link</a></li>
    </ol>
    <div id="some-content">
        <h2 id="test-1">First header</h2>
        <p>First content</p>
        <h2 id="test-2">Second header</h2>
        <p>Second content</p>
        <h2 id="test-3">Third header</h2>
        <p>Third content</p>
        <h2 id="test-4">Fourth header</h2>
        <p>Fourth content</p>
        <h2 id="test-5">Fifth header</h2>
        <p>Fifth content</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is twofold:

1. Do modern spiders follow anchor links?
2. If not, would only the last h2 and its following sibling be spidered?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and would be best on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I agree. At the time I didn't know better. :)

Comment: Meh, I can agree, it gets put [On Hold], but I can't delete it because @John Conde already answered it, so I get an automatic downvote. Boo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule spiders do not parse CSS. What CSS parsing they do typically has to do with finding possible cloaking through `display:none` and other tricks. **But** just using these CSS rules in-and-of themselves are not going to get a site into trouble as there are lots of legitimate uses for these rules. It's only when they are used for cloaking or other black hat SEO that a penalty will be incurred.

So if you can find the content in your HTML, and it is not created by CSS or JavaScript, then the spiders will find and index that content. If it is dynamically created by JavaScript or CSS then it will not be found by the spiders. (Google's crawlable Ajax does work with Google but that's a very bad way to go about building a site).

Comment: I suspected this to be true, but I've been having trouble getting corroborating documentation out of Google. Do you have any (preferably free, online) references?

Comment: I recently saw one. I'll check to see if I can find it.